# How to set ckeditor grails plugin to use database for upload files?

Tags: database, grails, ckeditor

How to set ckeditor grails to use database for upload files?

I just want to use database, because I cannot access file system to upload files there.

Answer (score 0):

The CKEditor plugin adds a filemanager controller class to handle the file saves. You have to override this controller with your own DB logic and add a UrlMapping to your controller.